# Angular2 - MaterializeCSS: Modal dialogs don't open

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, router, materialize

I'm using Angular2 with materializecss.
At the moment I'm trying to create modal dialogs which open on button click. There is also an example in the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize.

I also use a materilize-select which works perfectly fine, so I guess the installation, imports etc. are correct.

The problem is, when I click the modal-trigger the router resolves the new Route "localhost:4200/#modal1" and I'm redirected to my startpage.

I also tried to replace href with `data-target="modal1"` but that didn't work either.

Can I somehow disable the Hash-Links for the Router? My other routes are without hashes.

Heres the example from npm docs. I copied this part 1:1.

```
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a materialize="leanModal" [materializeParams]="[{dismissible: false}]" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help/hints are appreciated!

Edit: I changed the anchor to call a function on click

```
<a materialize="leanModal" [materializeParams]="[{dismissible: false}]" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" (click)="openModal()>Modal</a>
```

which triggers

```
$('#modal1').openModal()
```

But now I get an error:
[j.velocity is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSYxu.png)

Edit 2:

Got it to open the modals by using jQuery instead of $. I still get the error and the Application is stuck after opening the modal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution. Was quite frustrating to get there but here it is:

I reinstalled everything that was related to materialize + angular-cli, being angular2-materialize, materialize-css, jquery and hammerjs (which does not need to be installed manually).

Then I followed the instruction from [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize#installing--configuring-angular2-materialize-in-projects-created-with-angular-cliwebpack-100-beta11-webpack8) and removed the part which imports material-css in app.module.ts.

```
import "materialize-css";
```

And after that everything works just fine. No need to alter the webpack settings in angular2-materialize package or anything like that. My versions are:

- angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.16
- angular2-materialize 5.2.1
- materialize-css 0.97.7
- jquery 2.2.4

I hope that I can save other people some frustrating hours I had with that.

Comment: happy to hear I got someone out of the trouble I had ;)

Comment: Remove import "materialize-css"; and put it where ?

Comment: Remove, like it is not needed. In my app.module, I simply import the MaterializeModule. That´s it!

Comment: Strange that angular2-materialize instruction on npmjs does require you to import both. But yes, removing materialize-css works!

Answer (score 1):

I might be late for this, but you put those two attributes in modal trigger `<a>` rather than the modal `<div>` itself.

I also did exactly same mistake as OP, but after reading the [angular2-materialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize) page carefully, I corrected my code as mentioned below.

Instead of this

```
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a materialize="leanModal" [materializeParams]="[{dismissible: false}]" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
```

You have to put like:

```
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal" materialize="leanModal" [materializeParams]="[{dismissible: false}]"> 
... 
</div>
```

Three points to note here:

- there are no special attributes in `<a>` i.e. the trigger
- in place of `materialize="leanModal"`, it is `materialize="modal"` in modal
- didn't need to remove `import "materialize-css";` in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use open\close programmatically by:

1. handle (click)="openModal()" on the href
2. $('#modal1').openModal(); inside the openModal() function
3. remove the href="#modal1"
4. having a closeModal() function with $('#modal1').closeModal();

see http://materializecss.com/modals.html when the doc says:

> You can also open modals programatically, the below code will make your modal open on document ready:

Comment: Thanks for the answer dokkis. Unfortunately I get an TypeError: j.velocity is not a function at jQuery.openModal (materialize.js:2). I´ll do a little research on that error.

Comment: I use Angular-cli with webpack and I´m new to it :/ So I guess I need to import something instead of using require right?

Comment: try here: https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/issues/20 there is a webpack config where a guy says: "I think I found something. Webpack isolates jQuery and for some reason MaterializeCSS needs a window.jQuery object. So, i've added the following config in webpack to solve the problem (Notice the creation of window.jQuery in there, to provide MaterializeCSS with what it expects):" for some reason seems that you need to access to jQuery not to $ for a "bug" due to velocity described here: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1229

Comment: I´m puzzled about all this.

Comment: I got the modals to open but still get the error. I´m wondering because my webconfig for materilze already included the mentioned "window.jQuery": "jquery". What I did is using jQuery('#modal1').openModal(); instead of $.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand, now the modal shows up but you get the same error?

Comment: Exactly. When I swap from $ to jQuery the modal shows up but same error. I think it is something regarding jquery versions or multiple jquery instances. I just didn't have the time to check that yet. I'll let you know when I found sth. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

Face same problem and above solutions not help me on this, so write a new answer

Just add `$('.modal').modal();` in your components constructor.

```
import ... './stuff'
declare var $: any
@Component{...}
export class EditBlogComponent ...{
   constructor(){
   //Initialize modal here solve my 
   $('.modal').modal();

   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you use the same thing as I. Do you have https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize installed? Seems as if you are using vanilla materialze. Not the angular package.